# SCP transfer only modified files

Tags: linux, centos, rsync, scp

I'm using below command to transfer files cross server

```
scp -rc blowfish /source/directory/* username@domain.net:/destination/directory
```

Is there a way to transfer only files modified files just like `update` command for `cp`?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

[`rsync`](http://rsync.samba.org/) is your friend.

```
rsync -ru /source/directory/* username@domain.net:/destination/directory
```

If you want it to delete files at the destination that no longer exist at the source, add the `--delete` option.

Comment: Although, if you are syncing to a web server and that server caches HTML, you might not want to use `--delete`, since visitors on a stale page might request an asset that no longer exists.

Comment: @Jackson a clean process will not include variable data like caches or configs in the sources.

Comment: In some cases I have deal with servers outside of my domain that don't have `rsync` but have `scp`. Is there a comparable solution, even if it needs a few lines of scripting?

Comment: The answer is helpful, but the question was can this be achieved with scp itself.

Comment: @MladenB. How it can be achieved by scp?

Comment: Is rsync as safe as scp?

Answer (score 10):

Generally one asks for scp because there is a reason. I.e. can't install rsyncd on the target.

```
files=`find . -newermt "-3600 secs"`

for file in $files
do
       sshpass -p "" scp "$file" "root@$IP://usr/local/www/current/$file"
done
```

Comment: Note that "-cmin N" is maybe a tad simpler.  While N is a number of minutes the argument can be also a fractional number, e.g. "-cmin -0.5" gives you the files created in the last 30 seconds. In my experiments the argument had to be negative, tough.

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
remote_sum=$(ssh ${remote} sha256sum ${dest_filename})
remote_sum=${remote_sum%% *}
local_sum=$(sha256sum ${local_filename})
local_sum=${local_sum%% *}
if [[ ${local_sum} != ${remote_sum} ]]; then
  scp ${local_filename} ${remote}:${remote_filename}
fi
```

This is okay for one file but will be a bit slow for lots of files, depending on how quickly SSH can do repeated connections.  If you have controlmasters set up on your SSH connection it might not be too bad.  If you need to copy a while directory tree recursively, you could do a single SSH command that does sums on all the files, shove the result into a bash associative array, do the same on the local host, then compare file sums to decide whether to do the copy.  But it's almost certainly easier to install rsync on the remote.